# How to get recent comment link

Tags: comments

I'm getting 5 recent comments into my sidebar using the following code:

```
<?php $recent_comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
<?php foreach ($recent_comments as $comment) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, '60' ); ?> </a>
        <div>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->ID); ?>" title="on <?php echo $comment->post_title; ?>"><?php echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?>   </a><br />
            <span><?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 35 ); ?>...</span>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php }  ?>
```

But the problem that I am facing is: When I click on the comment link it's redirecting me to the current page instead of the page that is commented. On other hand, when I click on the comment link (that is in sidebar) in homepage, it's redirecting me to the latest post page.

I have used `wp_reset_query()` but the problem persists.
Also usingt `get_comment($comment->ID);`  instead of `get_permalink` is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code , you have not used the correct output variables.

```
<?php $recent_comments = get_comments('status=approve&number=5'); ?>
          <?php foreach ($recent_comments as $comment) { ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><?php echo get_avatar( $comment, '60' ); ?> </a>
                <div>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>" title="on <?php echo get_the_title($comment->comment_post_ID); ?>"><?php echo strip_tags($comment->comment_author); ?>   </a><br />
                    <span><?php echo wp_html_excerpt( $comment->comment_content, 35 ); ?>...</span>
                </div>

            </li>
        <?php }  ?>
```